# Save a bitmap to android gallery

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap, image-gallery

am developing a face recognition app. it gets the first bitman on a previous activity but it generates a new one with the faces labeled and i'd like to save that new bitmap. i've lost one day or two figuring it out but none of the answers i've tried helps.

this is the code for this activity, its supposed to save the bitmap into gallery when saveButton is pressed.

```
public class FaceRecognizeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Bitmap bmp, carasReconocidas;
    ImageView imagen;
    int contador;
    Button guardarRostro, copiarRegistroRostro;
    TextView descripcion;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentLight));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reconocer_rostros);
        guardarRostro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guardarRostros);
        copiarRegistroRostro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copiarRostros);
        descripcion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descripcionRostros);
        byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        this.imagen = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.caraReconocida);
        imagen.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        contador = 0;
        final Paint boxPaint = new Paint();
        carasReconocidas = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas (carasReconocidas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0,0,null);
        boxPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        boxPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        boxPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        procesar( canvas, boxPaint);
        descripcion.setText(cantidad());

        guardarRostro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    //TODO
            }
        })
        ;
        copiarRegistroRostro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Registro de rostros ", descripcion.getText().toString());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "copiado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        ;
    }

    public void procesar(Canvas canvas, Paint boxPaint){
        FaceDetector faceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
                .build();
        if (!faceDetector.isOperational()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Algo salió mal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bmp).build();
        SparseArray<Face> sparseArray = faceDetector.detect(frame);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < sparseArray.size(); i++){
            Face face = sparseArray.valueAt(i);
            float x1= face.getPosition().x;
            float y1= face.getPosition().y;
            float x2= x1 + face.getWidth();
            float y2= y1 + face.getHeight();
            RectF rectF = new RectF(x1,y1,x2,y2);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF,2,2, boxPaint);
            contador=contador + 1;
        }
        imagen.setImageBitmap(carasReconocidas);
    }

    public String cantidad(){
        String texto;
        if (contador == 0){
            texto= "Parece que no hay personas en esta imagen.";
        } else if (contador == 1) {
            texto="Se reconoció una persona";
        }else {
            texto="Se reconocieron " + Integer.toString(contador) + " personas.";
        }
        return texto;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent anotherIntent = new Intent(FaceRecognizeActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(anotherIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not reacting on comments. And we still do not know how a bitmap would be saved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375741/save-in-gallery-and-share-a-bitmap-on-android-java 'The Gallery' does not contain bitmaps.

Comment: am so sorry, i know gallery doesn't contain bitmaps, i'm assuming theres a way to convert a bitmap to jpeg or png to be saved but i've tryed some and i get a null pointer exception

Comment: Please put that info in your post. And add the logcat.